# How to get all post text with proper formatting in scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get data from wordpress blog. Struggling with understanding of what to be done to see it as a copy paste from browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Saxon/C for Python and this XPath 2.0 expression `string-join(//body//text())` you could get :

```
  This is a paragraph.
  Is this a link?

  Apparently.


  Nothing to add.
  Except maybe this other link.
```

You can then make a final cleanup with some regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I think installation is hard. Maybe after several years when it will be included in most packages. Also don't want to dig deeper  into http://www.saxonica.com/license/license.xml

Comment: Instructions for installing Saxon/C Python extension you can find here: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!starting/installingpython
Any problem please let us know. Also for what you are doing you should be able to use the opensource version: Saxon-HE/C

Answer (score 0):

This works without considering styles: (also maybe some tags should be added to the array of block tags).

```
def add_line_ending(html):
    from lxml import etree
    f = etree.HTML(html)
    tags = ["p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "ol", "ul", "pre", "br", "address", "blockquote", "dl", "div", "fieldset", "form", "hr", "noscript", "table"]
    for r in f.xpath('//*'):
        if r.tag in tags:
            if r.tail is None:
                r.tail = "\n"
            else:
                r.tail = r.tail + "\n"
    print(etree.tostring(f,pretty_print=True))
    return "".join(f.xpath("//text()"))



add_line_ending("<p>1<a>2<p>3,<a>)</a>2</p><span>3</span>5</a>2</p>")
html = '''<body><h3>Getting Ready to PCS to Hawaii?</h3> <p> If you are like my husband and me, we were beyond excited to receive the news we’d be moving back to paradise. But of course, we were nervous as it’s always a big deal to make the move.</p> <p><img class="alignnone wp-image-344478 size-full" src="https://about.hawaiilife.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/christian-bowen-8p6aqYxVqs4-unsplash-e1582822748516.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="474"></p> <h3>Here Are Some Tips for PCSing from the US Mainland to Hawaii:</h3> <h4>Temporary Lodging</h4> <p>Figure out what the best lodging is for you (and your family). We took full advantage of the <a href="https://www.hawaiimilitarylife.org/templodging" target="_blank" rel="noopener">local hotels that offer TLA</a> rates. It’s a great excuse to enjoy the Waikiki lifestyle for a bit. We enjoyed our stay at the <a href="https://www.alohilaniresort.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Alohilani Resort.</a> The <a href="https://www.halekoa.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Hale Koa</a> is a great option as well.</p> <h4>Take Time to Figure Out Which City/Neighborhood is Best for YOU</h4> <p>If you are new or unfamiliar with Oahu. It’s important to take the time to explore the various cities on the island. Each city and even neighborhood offers its own uniqueness. The process of buying property in Hawaii becomes much simpler once you’ve narrowed down the location where you’d like to reside. Remember — location, location, location. My husband and I quickly made our decision to find a home in <a href="https://www.hawaiilife.com/blog/hawaii-kai-vibes/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Hawaii Kai</a> and have not regretted it since!</p> <p><img class="alignnone wp-image-343934 size-full" src="https://about.hawaiilife.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/IMG_1697-e1582822110138.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="1288"></p> <h4>Furry Family Members</h4> <p>We can’t forget our furry family members! For good reason, Hawaii has strict guidelines on bringing pets to the Islands. Please visit the <a href="http://hdoa.hawaii.gov/ai/aqs/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Animal Quarantine Branch</a> for more information.</p> <h3>Are You Considering Buying Property During Your Time on Oahu?</h3> <p>Find the right realtor for you! I know, I sound biased considering this is my full-time job. But, if you are even slightly considering buying a home here in Hawaii, <a href="https://www.hawaiilife.com/agents/kaetyenostsukamoto" target="_blank" rel="noopener">contact me</a>. Realtors offer more than just opening up doors — we are here to negotiate on your behalf. We are here to share the knowledge we have to offer. Mostly, we are here to have your back! I was born and raised on the island of Oahu and have a lot to share when it comes to the culture here. Although my husband and I have been stationed in Washington State and San Diego during his time as a Naval Officer — Hawaii is my forever home, and I would love to help you create a home in Hawaii while you are here serving our great nation.</p> <p><img class="alignnone wp-image-343933 size-full" src="https://about.hawaiilife.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/ACS_0002-e1582822142853.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="1067"></p></body>'''
add_line_ending(html)

with open(r"D:\aa.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(add_line_ending(html))
```

Comment: I've found this solution after several days of searching. Hope this helps.